# how to write out multiple files in R?

Tags: r

I am a newbie R user. Now, I have a question related to write out multiple files with different names. Lets says that my data has the following structure:

```
IV_HAR_m1<-matrix(rnorm(1:100), ncol=30, nrow = 2000)
DV_HAR_m1<-matrix(rnorm(1:100), ncol=10, nrow = 2000)
```

I am trying to estimate multiple LASSO regressions. At the beginning, I was storing the iterations in one object called `Dinamic_beta`. This object was stored in only one file, and it saves the required information each time that my code iterate.

For doing this I was using `stew` which belongs to `pomp` package, but the total process takes 5 or 6 days and I am worried about a power outage or a fail in my computer.

Now, I want to save each environment (iterations) in a .Rnd file. I do not know how can I do that? but the code that I am using is the following:

```
library(glmnet)
library(Matrix)
library(pomp)


  space <-  7 #THE NUMBER OF FILES THAT I would WANT TO CREATE

  Dinamic_betas<-array(NA, c(10, 31, (nrow(IV_HAR_m1)-space)))
  dimnames(Dinamic_betas) <- list(NULL, NULL)

  set.seed(12345)  
  stew( #stew save the enviroment in a .Rnd file
file = "Dinamic_LASSO_RD",{ # The name required by stew for creating one file with all information
  for (i in 1:dim(Dinamic_betas)[3]) {
    tryCatch( #print messsages
      expr = {
        cv_dinamic <- cv.glmnet(IV_HAR_m1[i:(space+i-1),],
                                DV_HAR_m1[i:(space+i-1),], alpha = 1, family = "mgaussian", thresh=1e-08, maxit=10^9)
        LASSO_estimation_dinamic<- glmnet(IV_HAR_m1[i:(space+i-1),], DV_HAR_m1[i:(space+i-1),],
                                          alpha = 1, lambda = cv_dinamic$lambda.min, family = "mgaussian")
        coefs <- as.matrix(do.call(cbind, coef(LASSO_estimation_dinamic)))
        Dinamic_betas[,,i] <- t(coefs)
      },
      error = function(e){
        message("Caught an error!")
        print(e)
      },
      warning = function(w){
        message("Caught an warning!")
        print(w)
      },
      finally = {
        message("All done, quitting.")
      }
    )
    if (i%%400==0) {print(i)}
  }
}
  )
```

If someone can suggest another package that stores the outputs in different files I will grateful.

Comment: Do you want to save a separate file for each iteration? This could lead to storage problems and alot of redundancy. Or do you want to overwrite previous iteration with current iteration when it completes (ie no power failiurs)?

Comment: @JustGettinStarted I want to save a separate file for each iteration and I now that could lead to storage problems. I want to do this because i am worried about a power outage and lost all my information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this just before the close of your loop

`save.image(paste0("Results_iteration_",i,".RData"))`

This should save your entire workspace to disk for every iteration. You can then use `load()` to load the workspace of every environment. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @Eve Chanatasig, if this answer works please mark the question as answered, if not please provide feedback so we can move forward